# PWA + Capacitor.JS: Failed to register a service worker (in Android)

Tags: progressive-web-apps, capacitor

I’m struggling with the following error for some time:

> TypeError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope (‘http://localhost/’) with script (‘http://localhost/sw.js’): An unknown error occurred when fetching the script.

Link to the project files: https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-pwa-capacitor-v03xc3

What could be the issue here? Thank you in advance. If any additional details needed, please let me know.

Basically I took the PWA example from here: https://github.com/mdn/pwa-examples/tree/main/a2hs
Then followed the instructions for capacitor here: https://capacitorjs.com/docs/getting-started#add-capacitor-to-your-web-app

**In the browser runs fine**, service worker registers ok.

However, when running in Android Emulator, using:

> npx cap sync;
> npx cap open android

The error above shows up.
I also tried setting server.androidScheme to 'https'. The address changes to https://localhost, but the same error shows up (with https instead of http).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by adding a `server.hostname` to my `capacitor.config.ts`. It appears the Android webview doesn't allow service worker registration on the default `localhost` hostname. This is what it looks like:

```
server: {
    // the default hostname (localhost) does not allow android to load a service worker
    hostname: "my-app",
  }
```

Comment: Facing the same issue but how can this be the solution given in the latest capacitor docs they still recommend it to keep this as `localhost`?

"It is recommended to keep this as `localhost` as it allows the use of
Web APIs that would otherwise require a [secure
context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Secure_Contexts)"

... also, will it not impact the iOS app in an unexpected manner?